# If statement running even when condition is wrong

Tags: typescript, if-statement, boolean, logic, conditional-statements

[image]

i checked in log and the value of isSubmissionUsingUrl is true . i also tried !self.isSubmissionUsingUrl. but it is same.
As per the code the if statement should not be executed. If value of isSubmissionUsingUrl is true.

Comment: Where does the self.isSubmissionUsingUrl flag become true? Have you tried checking that?

Comment: I have checked the value of isSubmissionUsingUrl in console and it is true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to console log if your condition is really "false".

```
console.log(self.isSubmissionsUsingUrl === false && submissionFile === null || submissionFile === '');
```

If it is true then try to console log subsets of your condition.

I don't know what you are trying to achieve but it seems that you probably miss a parenthesis.
You may need:

```
if (self.isSubmissionsUsingUrl === false && (submissionFile === null || submissionFile === '')) {...}
```